# Dynamically assigning object keys results in last key being contained with double quotes

Tags: javascript

I've created a CSV parser and have run into an interesting situation. When the onLoad function is hit, the last key of my object `row` is double quoted. I'm looking for an explanation of why. Anyone know?

*Comments contains sample values*

```
const results = [];
const lines = reader.result.split('\n');
//lines = ["accountId,nickname,rando", "test-arn,test-nickname,test-rando"]
const keys = lines[0].split(',');
//keys = ["accountId", "nickname", "rando"]

forEach((line) => { 
    // line = "test-arn, test-nickname, test-rando"
    const values = line.split(','); 
    // values = ["test-arn", "test-nickname", "test-rando"]
    const row = {}; 

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let key = keys[i];
        row[key] = values[i];
    }

    //row = { accountId: "test-arn", nickname="test-nickname", "rando": "test-rando"}
    results.push(row);
}, lines);
```

You can see that the key `rando` inside `row` is surrounded by double quotes

```
row = { 
    accountId: "test-arn", 
    nickname: "test-nickname", 
    "rando": "test-rando",
}
```

**Sample CSV**

```
accountId,nickname,rando^M
test-arn,test-nickname,test-rando^M
```

**Full Function**

```
const parseCsv = ({ file, before, onSuccess, onError }) => {
    before();
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
        const results = [];
        const lines = reader.result.split('\n');
        const keys = lines[0].split(',');

        forEach((line) => { 
            const values = line.split(','); 
            const row = {}; 

            for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                let key = keys[i];
                row[key] = values[i];
            }
            results.push(row);
        }, lines);

        onSuccess(results);
    };

    reader.onError = (error) => {
        onError(error);
    };
};
```

Comment: and how does the file you read look like?

Comment: please attach the file

Comment: *Sample CSV* Added

Comment: what's `^M` for in `test-rando^M`?

Comment: It's VI's notation for newline. 
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it

Answer (score 0):

I've found that there is a return character being left in the last key.

In the console:

```
keys
>(3) ["accountId", "nickname", "rando"] 
JSON.strigify(keys)
>"["accountId","nickname","rando\r"]"
```

Resolution is to remove the return character

```
const results = [];
const lines = reader.result.split('\n');
const header = lines.shift().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ''); //Remove newline characters
const keys = header.split(',');

forEach((line) => {
    const values = line.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').split(',');
    const row = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        row[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }

    results.push(row);
}, lines);

onSuccess(results);
```